# Spring Data JPA check if a SET contains an object

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data, object-persistence

I have a domain object called Device with this property

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Driver> authorizedDrivers = new HashSet<>();
```

I would like to make this query, but I got an error **(antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected AST node: ()**

```
@Query("select dev from Device dev where dev.authorizedDrivers.contains(?1) ")
Set<Device> findDeviceByDriver(Driver driver);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[JPQL](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_01/ejb3_langref.html) does not have 'contains' expression. You can try this query:

```
@Query("select dev from Device dev join dev.authorizedDrivers d where d = ?1")
Set<Device> findDeviceByDriver(Driver driver);
```